# Can't install Socialite on Laravel Homestead: memory limit error

Tags: laravel, out-of-memory, homestead, laravel-socialite

I'm using php 7.4 in Laravel Homestead and edited this file

```
etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
```

And set

```
memory_limit = -1
```

I reloaded homestead and checked `phpinfo()` in the HomeController and it's been changed to `-1` but every time I try to install socialite

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

I get

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in 
phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in 
phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle 
out of memory errors
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. > php -i | grep 'php.ini'
2. > /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini          memory_limit=-1
3. > sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
4. > php -r "echo ini_get ('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"

Answer (score 0):

If you edit `php.ini`. You may need to restart xampp/wamp.

If it doesn't work, Be sure that your composer itself is updated to the latest version:

```
php composer.phar --self-update
```

You can increase memory limit for composer temporarily by adding the composer memory limit environment variable:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=128MB php composer.phar update
```

Use -1 to Ignore Memory limit completely.

Another way to increase the PHP memory limit:

```
php -d memory_limit=512M composer.phar update
```

Comment: in which path should I run these commands? Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: updated composer and set memory to -1 but still getting the issue

Answer (score 0):

You may need to increase the VM's memory so that the php running inside could consume as much memory as possible when `memory_limt` has been set to -1.

for eg.

```
// file Homestead.yaml

ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 3072 // instead of 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
```

make sure to reload the VM with `vagrant reload`